# Is it possible to adjust the "quantization" of allowable skip lengths?

Tags: tex-core, lengths, dimensions

In plain TeX and derivative formats, the concept of stretchable/shrinkable length, AKA a *glue* or a *skip* or a *rubber length* exists, in general defined as

```
<dimen> plus <stretch-dimen> minus <shrink-dimen>
```

where `<dimen>` is the base dimension and `<stretch-dimen>` and `<shrink-dimen>` are the maximum stretch and shrink values, respectively. The skip length will adjust within these bounds to fit its container.

Since the smallest unit of TeX computation is the scaled point, `1sp`, I assume that all stretch/shrink computations are quantized at this level.

Is it possible to change the "unit of quantization" for skip lengths? My thought is that it's not, because this is deep down at (inside) the primitive. But I'm far from a TeXpert, and if it were possible, I think it could be useful for grid-like typesetting tasks.

Here is a much-simplified MWE that sets up the general idea with plain TeX code:

```
\def\z{\hbox to 0pt{\hss\strut\vrule\hss}}
\def\zz{\z\hskip4pt}
\def\zzz{\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz}
x\z\hskip12pt plus 12pt minus 0pt %step 4pt
\z

x\z\hskip16pt plus 12pt minus 0pt %step 4pt
\z

x\hbox to 23pt{\z\hfill\hskip16pt plus 12pt minus 0pt %step 4pt
\z\hfill}

x\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
\bye
```

which produces:

[image]

In the first two lines, the base dimension is used, so the rules align with the "grid" (the last line). However, in the penultimate line, a stretch component is used that is not a multiple of the grid spacing, so the rule is not aligned.

Is there a way to adjust the "quantization" so that the stretch component snaps to the nearest multiple of the grid spacing (here, `4pt`)?

Comment: Use  \scalebox{20000.0}{...}?

Comment: Sorry @JohnKormylo, I don't think that will do what I want. Won't that just scale the contents, or am I missing something?

Comment: Multiplying by 20000 converts 1sp to 4pt.  Seriously though, you should probably use \pgfmathparse to do the calculations.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible, but I also think that it wouldn't be so useful. Don't forget that the text can have different width or height -- replace one x by i or change the font size -- and you wouldn't want to use only unproportional fonts and one font size in grid typesetting. So you don't need quantized stretch spaces but a mean to go to the next grid position.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my point was that _a way to go to the next grid position_ already exists in the skip mechanism, except that the "grid" has a `1sp` spacing. If this could be changed for certain skips, things like `Par 1\par\vfill Par 2\par\vfill Par 3`, for example, could automatically fall onto the grid.

Comment: You are going to the next grid position with such steps only if you are currently on a grid position - which you can't know. In your example try `x\hskip4pt\z` and `m\hskip4pt\z`: a step of 4pt doesn't ensure you are on the grid so what would you gain if stretch and shrink would be done in 4pt-steps?.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the example is in horizontal mode just for simplicity (and because I couldn't think of a concise example in plain, this is my lack of plain TeX knowledge showing), but for grid typesetting, if one (the first) baseline is on the grid and all vertical skips can be quantized with respect to `\baselineskip`, then all lines will end up aligned to the grid. To be sure, there would be other problems to solve here too; I just wondered if the idea was even possible.

Comment: In vertical mode you would have the same problems (or more). That's why I mentioned font sizes (which would change the baselineskip). And boxes have two dimensions (height and depth) which can get quite large - see graphics, minipages, tabulars, display math.

Comment: @PaulGessler You wrote:  where `<stretch-dimen>` and `<shrink-dimen>` are the maximum stretch and shrink values, respectively. This is not exactly true. You are right for `<shring-dimen>` but `<stretch-dimen>` has nothing to do with a maximum. If this dimen is exactly reached then badness=100, but badness can be (and usually is) greater than 100, i.e. the `<stretch-dimen>` is exceeded. I am unable to describe the exact algorithm in this 600 characters of the comment.

Comment: at scalebox{20000}. IMHO this is not a way to solution, because you need to scale down (by 1/20000) all typesetting material, so the less precision will manifest in all typesetting: positions of all letters, not only scalable glue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation of "plus and minus" results are done in TeX using computer-dependent implementation of numbers, so Knuth decided that there will be no possibility to access these results by macro programmer in order to disable of creating computer-dependent results in document by macro language.

I suggest the macro `\roundto{dimen}`. This macro recalculates the width of the previous box to the multiply of "dimen". The usage in our example would be:

```
x\hbox to 23pt{\z\hfill\hskip16pt plus 12pt minus 0pt \z\hfill}

x\hbox{\z\hskip16pt}\hbox to\dimexpr(23pt-16pt)/2{\hfil}\roundto{4pt}\z

x\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
```

Your example (first line) includes fixed `\hskip16pt` plus `2*\hfill` in 23pt. So each `\hfill` takes `(23pt-16pt)/2` space. The `\z` is after first `\hfill` so the second box in my example has this dimension. And the `\roundto` macro rounds the width of this box to multiple of 4pt. The `\z` is printed after rounding.

The `\roundbox` macro can be implemented like this:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\roundto#1{\setbox0=\lastbox \tmpnum=\wd0 \dimen0=#1\relax
   % \advance\tmpnum by\dimexpr \dimen0/2\relax
   % uncomment this ^ ^, if you need "central" roundning
   % \advance\tmpnum by\dimen0 \advance\tmpnum by-1
   % uncomment this ^ ^, if you need "upper" roundning
   \divide\tmpnum by\dimen0 \multiply\tmpnum by\dimen0
   \wd0=\the\tmpnum sp
   \box0
}
```

Meaningful usage of `\roundto` macro:

```
x\hbox{\z various text\quad}\roundto{4pt}\z next text is aligned.

x\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
```